# Accessing properties of one nib from another

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nib

I have two nibs `WindowA` and `WindowB` both of which are created when I launch my program. I am trying to access properties of `WindowA` programmatically from the class associated with the `WindowB` nib.

What I am currently doing is creating an object of `WindowA` in `WindowB` like so:

```
WindowA* winA = [[WindowA alloc] initWithNibName: @"WindowA" bundle:nil];
```

This does not work and I am suspecting that all I am doing is just creating a new instance of `WindowA` and not using the current one.

My `WindowA.h` looks like this:

```
@interface WindowA : NSViewController{

     IBOutlet NSButton* aButton;

}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView* aTableView;

-(IBAction) buttonPress: (id)sender;
-(void) setColor;
```

My `WindowA.m` looks like this:

```
#import "WindowA.h"

@synthesize aTableView;

-(void) dealloc{

     [aTableView release];
}

-(void) awakeFromNib {

}

-(id) init{

    self = [super init];

    if (self){

       aTableView = [[NSTableView alloc] init];

    }

    return self;
}

-(IBAction) buttonPress: (id) sender; 
{
   [aTableView setBackgroundColor: NSColor.blueColor];
}

-(void)
```

My `WindowB.h` looks like this:

```
@interface WindowB : NSViewController {

     NSButton* bButton;    

}

@property (nonatomic) WindowA* winA;

-(IBAction) buttonClick :(id) sender;
```

My `WindowB.m` looks like this:

```
#import "WindowB.h"

-(void) dealloc {

   [winA release];

 }

-(void) awakeFromNib {

}

-(id) init {

     WindowA* winA = [[WindowA alloc] initWithNibName: @"WindowA" bundle:nil];
}

-(IBActon) buttonClick :(id) sender {

   winA.setColor;

 }
```

All I want to do is access `WindowA` from `WindowB`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Can you check if `winA` is nil in `buttonClick` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 WindowA* winA = [[WindowA alloc] initWithNibName: @"WindowA" bundle:nil];
```

Above line doesn't work because you are calling initWithNibName() of WindowA class and that is not written there. So Add these lines in your both controller classes - -

```
@implementation your_controler_name

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
  }
  return self;
}
```

To Access properties of windowA from windowB --- Firstly make object of windowA in windowB class (as you are creating) and then access that property with dot operator (ie   yourObj.propertyName) .